# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (410,410) into shape (28,28)

Tags: python

I am trying to read a dataset of QR Codes into this program. I tested it using a MNIST dataset and it worked just fine but when I put my QR Dataset in (which has the same number of entries as the MNIST dataset) I get this error:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (410,410) into shape (28,28)

This is the code:

```
def read_MNIST_Data(self):
    train = np.empty((1000,28,28),dtype='float')
    trainY = np.zeros((1000))
    test = np.empty((10000,28,28),dtype='float')
    testY = np.zeros((10000))
    # Load in the images
    i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir('C:/Users/trifo/Downloads/Train-20221025T200820Z-001/Train_Project'):
        y = int(filename[0])
        trainY[i] = y
    *** train[i] = cv2.imread('C:/Users/trifo/Downloads/Train-20221025T200820Z-001/Train_Project/{0}'.format(filename),0)/255.0 ***
        # scale between 0-1, for color, use 1
        i = i + 1

    i = 0 # read test data
    for filename in os.listdir('C:/Users/trifo/Downloads/test'):
        y = int(filename[0])
        testY[i] = y
        test[i] = cv2.imread('C:/Users/trifo/Downloads/test/{0}'.format(filename),0)/255.0 
        i = i + 1
    trainX = train.reshape(train.shape[0],1,train.shape[1],train.shape[2])
    testX = test.reshape(test.shape[0],1,test.shape[1],test.shape[2])
    return trainX, trainY, testX, testY

def get_train_test_loaders(self, train_batch_size, test_batch_size):
    trainX, trainY, testX, testY = self.read_MNIST_Data()
    x_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(trainX).float().to(Utils.device)
    y_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(trainY).float().to(Utils.device)
    x_test_tensor = torch.from_numpy(testX).float().to(Utils.device)
    y_test_tensor = torch.from_numpy(testY).float().to(Utils.device)
    # load tensors into dataset
    trainds = MyDataSet(x_train_tensor, y_train_tensor)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=trainds, batch_size=train_batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
    testds = MyDataSet(x_train_tensor, y_train_tensor)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=testds, batch_size=test_batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
    return train_loader, test_loader

def plot_images(loader):
    mnistdata = iter(loader)
    digit, label = next(mnistdata)
    for i in range(6):
        plt.subplot(2,3,i+1)
        img = digit[i].cpu()
        plt.imshow(img.reshape(28,28), cmap="gray")
    plt.show()
```

The line that I marked with the "***" is the one that is generating the error. Dees anyone have any suggestion on how to remove this error?

Comment: you need your images to be 28x28.

Comment: you should add more specific tags to your question

Comment: numpy's reshape doesn't change the total size of an array, it just, well, reshapes it...You want to use one of many "resize" functions, for instance opencv or something

Comment: Thanks for the information on resizing, I'm looking for information on that now. Any advice on where it should go?